# Rotating Proxy (STORM, SMART) not giving unique IP in each scrapy request

Tags: proxy, scrapy

How do I make sure I am getting new ip in each scrapy request? I tried with both stormproxies and smartproxies but the ip it gives is same for a session.

However, the ip is new on each run. But for a single session, the ip is same.

My code below:

```
import json
import uuid
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class IpTest(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'IP_test'
    previous_ip = ''
    count = 1
    ip_url = 'https://ifconfig.me/all.json'

    def start_requests(self,):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            self.ip_url,
            dont_filter=True,
            meta={
                'cookiejar': uuid.uuid4().hex,
                'proxy': MY_ROTATING_PROXY # either stormproxy or smartproxy
            }
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        ip_address = json.loads(response.text)['ip_addr']
        self.logger.info(f"IP: {ip_address}")
        if self.count < 10:
            self.count += 1
            yield from self.start_requests()


settings = {
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
}

process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(IpTest)
process.start()
```

Output logs:

```
2020-12-27 21:15:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-12-27 21:15:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-12-27 21:15:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-12-27 21:15:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: None)
2020-12-27 21:15:55 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:15:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:15:56 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:15:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:15:57 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:15:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:15:59 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:00 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:01 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:03 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:04 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:06 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ifconfig.me/all.json> (referer: https://ifconfig.me/all.json)
2020-12-27 21:16:07 [IP_test] INFO: IP: 190.239.69.94
2020-12-27 21:16:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I even tried disabling cookies (`COOKIES_ENABLED = False`), removing cookiejar from request.meta. But no luck.

Comment: Where do you rotate `MY_ROTATING_PROXY`? You seem to be always using the same variable for all requests. See https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies

Comment: @Gallaecio `MY_ROTATING_PROXY` is a proxy provider that already does the job. Are you familiar with stormproxies or smartproxies? If not, check those please. 

FYI, I already tried with `scrapy-rotating-proxies`. Basically, that is only a middleware which will ultimately set proxy in requests meta

Comment: Have you checked if the `IP` is yours or the proxy’s? If it’s the latter, then contact your smart proxy provider, maybe it’s not *that* smart :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was hard, but I found the answer. For Storm you need pass headers with 'Connection': 'close'. In this case you will get new proxy for each request. For example:

```
HEADERS = {'Connection': 'close'}
yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, body=body, headers=HEADERS)
```

In this case Storm will close connection ang give you new IP per request